# javascript merging parameters

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
StandardFormat({
    HeaderFont: 'greentext2',
    HeaderLinkFont: 'bluelink3',
    Backcolor: 'Black',
        ...
});
```

So far, I have a function that has this form:

```
FormatGrid(ID, HeaderFont, HeaderLinkFont, BackColor,...){}
```

All the parameters are listed and must be supplied in the call. What I'd like to do is replace it with this:

```
FormatGrid(ID, Format){}
```

That way, I could write something like this:

`FormatGrid('TopGrid', StandardFormat)`; and be able to send the id of the grid and any format object.

I'm kinda stuck. How do you merge the parameters?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do...

```
function FormatGrid(ID, Format) {
    var options;
    if (typeof Format != 'string') {
       options = Format;
    } else {
       options = {
          HeaderFont: arguments[1],
          HeaderLinkFont: arguments[2],
          Backcolor: arguments[3]
       }
    }

    // Here you could then access `options.HeaderFont`.
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KP3Hy/).

This unpacks to `window` however.

Comment: Is the if...else necessary? I just left options = Format; but it's not working when I write alert(options.HeaderFont);

Comment: @frenchie Do you want to allow both ways, the object literal *and* the parameters listed out?

Comment: Not sure what the difference is. Inside the function, I just want to write $(this).css('background-color', BackColor); and use the parameters that I'm putting into the object StandardFormat.

Comment: @frenchie In that case, you would need to unpack them into the function's scope.

Comment: How do I do that? That's what I'm looking to do.

Comment: I'm just looking for a simple 1-2 liner way of doing it. I have my function like this: function FormatGrid(ID, Format) {}. What do I need to write so that I can access either option.HeaderFont or HeaderFont. I don't understand the example in Fiddle.

Comment: For now, when I look at the Inspector in Chrome, I'm getting 2 errors: StandardFormat is not defined and HeaderFont is not defined (I'm just putting the first property to see what happens).

Comment: @frenchie Not everything is solvable with 1-2 lines. You should limit the access to the varable to only one way, either `options.HeaderFont` or `HeaderFont`. [I've asked a question myself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453636/how-can-i-unpack-an-object-into-a-functions-scope).

Comment: Do I need to use the eval statement to convert StandardFormat to an object?

Comment: ok, so I got rid of one error by writing "var StandardFormat = ({...});

Comment: I got the 1 liner answer! See below.

Comment: @frenchie The best practice is to access via `options.HeaderFont`.