# How can I *unpack* an object into a function's scope?

Tags: javascript, scope

I have this code...

```
function a(options) {
    for (var item in options) {
       if ( ! options.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
          continue;
       }
       this[item] = options[item];
    }
}

a({ 'abc': 'def' });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acQje/).

Whilst this unpacks variables from the object, it sets them to global scope (attached to `window`) because `this` is `window` in that circumstance.

So after the function I can do `alert(abc)` and it will alert `def`, which isn't good.

How would I set the scope of the variables to the function?

Comment: I think the only possibility would be to use `with` but normally it should be avoided.

Comment: @Felix Thanks, please post an answer :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript local variable declare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119335/javascript-local-variable-declare)

Comment: Like Felix said, you can use with, but I'm kinda curious why you would go through the trouble of unpacking that object into the function's scope. Couldn't you just use the options variable you passed in?

Comment: @Mrbuubuu I was answering [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453121), and the concept intrigued me.

Comment: @Jon Didn't find that one, I've cast my close vote as well.

Comment: @Alex: what does this line do: if (!options.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
   continue;
  }

Comment: @frenchie It ensures that if you have augmented the object, it won't iterate over other enumerable properties up the protoype chain.

Comment: @frenchie Basically it stops (possible) unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put the properties of the object in the scope of the function, you can *extend the scope* by using `with`:

```
function a(options) {
    with(options) {
        // properties of `options` are in the scope
        alert(abc);
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer**: [Make sure you read the documentation and about disadvantages of `with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with). It should be avoided and is also kind of deprecated:

> Using `with` is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 `strict` mode. The recommended alternative is to assign the object whose properties you want to access to a temporary variable.

So the questions is why not stick with `options` ?

Comment: +1 Thanks Felix, as for why, see my comment on the question :)

Comment: @alex: Yes, somehow I had the feeling it was related to this question (I read it earlier ;)).

Comment: As for me, I would always use a `options.optionA` pattern :)

Answer (score 2):

You can access the function from inside itself using the callee property:

```
function a(options) {
    var thiz = arguments.callee;
    for (var item in options) {
        if (!options.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            continue;
        }
        thiz[item] = options[item];
    }
}

a({
    'abc': 'def'
});

alert(a.abc);
```

Alternatively, you can set the scope when you call it:

```
function a(options) {
    for (var item in options) {
        if (!options.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            continue;
        }
        this[item] = options[item];
    }
}

a.call(a, {
    'abc': 'def'
});
alert(a.abc);
```

Comment: This does not really add the properties to the function scope. It sets it as properties of the function object.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I was going to try and avoid `callee` because it appears to be deprecated (for what reasons I'm unsure).

Comment: But maybe it is what @alex wanted ;)