# Javascript: unpack object as function parameters

Tags: javascript, python

I have a function, in Javascript

```
function asd(foo, bar, baz) {
    // ...
}
```

And each of those 3 arguments is required.

Suppose I have those arguments grouped as an object:

```
var x = {
    foo: 10,
    bar: 20,
    baz: 30
};
```

**Can I call function `asd` just by giving object `x` somehow "unpacked"?** Can this be done generically? i.e., not knowing the signature of `asd`.

I'm searching for something like kwargs unpacking in Python:

```
def asd(foo, bar, baz):
    # ...

kwargs = {'foo': 10, 'bar': 20, 'baz': 30}
asd(**kwargs)
```

A "no, not possible" answer is acceptable. I just want to know whether this is possible in Javascript.

Comment: There's no built-in way to do that. You could write a function to do it. *edit* actually writing a function would be problematic, since JavaScript imposes no particular ordering on properties of an object.

Comment: A function for that would be fine. But how?

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453636/how-can-i-unpack-an-object-into-a-functions-scope

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken - you really can't predict the ordering of object properties when you get them via `Object.keys()` or a `for ... in` loop.  Because that's undefined, you can't control the order in which you pass the property values to the function.

Comment: @James that question is somewhat different I think. This question is about how to use object properties as arguments in a function call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just making things clearer for people coming from Google like me:

**No, this is not possible** natively in JavaScript.

You have to implement something custom to achieve this (see the other answer).

Answer (score 13):

This is now possible in JavaScript. The other comment stating that it is not possible natively is not correct (and wasn't at time of posting). It was added roughly a year after you asked - adding an answer for people landing here many years later.

Your function simply needs to change to:

```
function asd({foo, bar, baz}) {
    // ...
}
```

and you call it like this:

```
var x = {
    foo: 10,
    bar: 20,
    baz: 30
};
asd(x);
```

See [MDN Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter).

Comment: This does not maintain the function signature `function add(foo, bar, baz)` as the original post wanted. There is still no built-in way to achieve this in JavaScript.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, I missed the "i.e., not knowing the signature of asd" portion. My mistake. Nonetheless, some google searches for object unpacking lead to this post, so I'll leave my answer up as an alternative for people getting here indirectly.

Answer (score 4):

```
function asd(foo, bar, baz) {
    console.log(foo, bar, baz);
}

var x = {
    foo: 10,
    bar: 20,
    baz: 30
};

var args = [];
for(var i in x){
    args.push(x[i]);
}
asd.apply(window, args);
```

But, like other people said, ordering is a problem. With for in you get the properties in the order that they were defined. If that's what you want, then this solution can work for you. But mapping parameters by name is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Answring to this old post, I implemented this solution that relies on the `spread` operator and on parsing the function argument names. It can be improved to accept also arrow function.

```js
Function.prototype.kwargs = function(argsObj){
  const rawArgs = this.toLocaleString().match(/\(.*\)\{/);
  if(!rawArgs){
    console.error("args parsing failed");
    return;
  }
  const argsList = rawArgs[0].replace(/\(|\)|\{/g, '').split(',');
  const args = argsList.map((param) => argsObj[param.trim()] || param);
  return this(...args);
}

function sum(a,b){
  return a+b;
}
const input = {a:1, b:2}
console.log(sum.kwargs({a:1, b:2}))


function sum2(a12,   b){
  return a12+b;
}
const input2 = {a12:1, b:2};
console.log(sum2.kwargs(input2));
```